# Jekyll: Have tags from custom collections included in site.tags?

Tags: collections, jekyll, categories, tagging

I have a Jekyll site with both Posts and Resource Pages, with the latter being a Jekyll collection of pages.

I've installed the [jekyll-tagging](https://github.com/pattex/jekyll-tagging) extension, which generates list pages for all tags listed in `site.tags`, and set up a tags index page which has a 'Tag Cloud'.

However tags defined in the Front Matter on the Resource Pages do not show up in `site.tags` (and so not in the Tag Cloud) and there is no documentation I can find on either Collections or Tags on how to configure which collections are indexed into the `site.tags` variable.

I tried manually enumerating the collection and adding the tags to the Tag Cloud, which worked, but I then realised that the jekyll-tagging plugin wasn't generating list pages for tags not listed in `site.tags`, so having the entries in the Tag Cloud was pretty pointless.

Is there a configuration option for Jekyll collections that tells it to include tags (and presumably also categories) from that collection?

Presumably, if that's not possible then the next best approach will be to locally modify jekyll-tagging to include configured collections?